# Rate of change question involving velocity, displacement and acceleration

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

I have been having trouble understanding questions c)-e) and am in need of some help:

An object is moving in a straight line from a fixed point. The displacement $s$ in metres is given by $s=-2t^2+28t+45$, $t\geq0$, where $t$ is in seconds.

$a)$ Find the velocity at any time:

$$v(t)=s'(t)=-2t^2+28t+45$$
$$v(t)=-4t+28$$
$$v(1)=-4(1)+28$$
$$v=24m/s$$

$b)$What is the velocity at $t=3s$?
$$v(3)=-4(3)+28$$
$$v=16m/s$$

$c)$Find $t$ when the object reaches its maximum displacement:

- Would this be when the velocity is equal to zero, find the critical points, second derivative test for a maximum?

$d)$Find the maximum displacement reached by this object:

- Probably plugging t from $c)$ into the initial function?

$e)$Determine the acceleration at any time:

I believe this is just the second derivative of the initial function or the first derivative of velocity?
$$a(t)=v'(t)=-4t+28\\$$
$$a(t)=-4m/s^2$$

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Since the displacement is a quadratic function, there is only one turning point, so there is no need to test for maximum / minimum

Comment: I believe letter (d) is asking about the point where $|s(0)-s(t)|$ is maximum, so through the first order condition $s'(t)=0$ you will find $t^*$ where it happens, which is letter (c) answer. PS: letter (a) answer is a function of $t$ since they ask for every time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to part a) is a formula which will give the velocity at time $t$. So, the answer should be $-4t+28$ m/s. I don't belive they are looking for the velocity at an arbitrary time that you choose. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the point brought up by @TimRaczkowski, you shouldn't write things like this:

$$a(t)=v'(t)=-4t+28\\$$

as they are mathematically incorrect. You can correct it simply, like so:

$$a(t)=v'(t)=(-4t+28)' = -4\\$$